# (uncaught exception)Error: ResizeObserver loop completed with undelivered notifications

Tags: javascript, cypress, uncaught-exception

[image: SS of the error I'm getting when trying to get element and use cy.type() command.]

I am trying to get an element and use Cypress type command but getting this error: ResizeObserver loop completed with undelivered notifications. Here is my code:

```
`get signatureBtn() {
        return cy.get('#signature').type('userName')
    }`
```

I use below code in my `support/e2e.js` file but still getting the error.

```
    Cypress.on('uncaught:exception', (err, runnable) => {
    if (err.message.includes('ResizeObserver loop completed with undelivered notifications.')) {
        // ignore the error
        return false
    }
})
```

Can somebody advise please why I am getting this error? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Uncaught exceptions are used for [app events](https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/catalog-of-events#App-Events). Your error is from your test code not app code.

Comment: Could be LastPass extension like in this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/76190200/6996515

Comment: I tried installing LastPass but could not replicate the error.

Answer (score 9):

The uncaught exception handler looks ok, but it looks possible that the exception is not caused by the `get #signature`, it just occurs during that command.

Since uncaught exception is thrown asynchronously from the app under test, it can be coming from a previous command that has an action that changes the page. For example, it's possible the click handler of `NextButton1` in causing it (or even something before that action).

To debug the problem, comment out your current handler.

Then add this code around the suspect line,

```js
const stub = cy.stub()
Cypress.on('uncaught:exception', (err, runnable) => {
  if (err.message.includes('ResizeObserver')) {
      stub()
      return false
  }
})

cy.get('#signature').type('userName')

cy.wrap(stub).should('have.been.called')
```

If `should('have.been.called')` fails, then it's not that line - move backwards in the test and check the previous line

```js
const stub = cy.stub()
Cypress.on('uncaught:exception', (err, runnable) => {
  if (err.message.includes('ResizeObserver')) {
      stub()
      return false
  }
})

cy.get('[data-test="NextButton"]').click()

cy.wrap(stub).should('have.been.called')
```

and so on until you find the line that is failing.

ResizeObserver is often used to provide animation, so once you find the line that causes the error, add a visibility check to allow the page to settle before testing `#signature`.

Something like

```js
cy.get('[data-test="NextButton"]').click()

cy.get('some-element-that-appears-after-click')
  .should('be.visible')                          // wait for animation
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Unfortunately, even when identifying the line - and if ResizeObserver error is caught and ignored via handler, then I start getting memory issues and cypress crashes. (even headless)

Comment: same here, when error ignored, App crashes.