# ResizeObserver loop completed with undelivered notifications. In Tabulator with React

Tags: reactjs, tabulator

Showing this Error when screen size changes.

Run Time error: ResizeObserver loop completed with undelivered notifications

I am using Tabulator in react for Data Tables.

This happens when I am doing Zoom in or Zoom out the browser screen.

Answer (score 1):

The "ResizeObserver loop completed with undelivered notifications" error in React with Tabulator often occurs due to rapid resizing of elements. To resolve it:

Update Dependencies: Ensure you're using the latest React and Tabulator versions.

Debounce Resize Events: Use a debounce function to limit resize event frequency.

ResizeObserver Polyfill: Consider using a polyfill for consistent behavior.

```
const handleResize = debounce(() => {
}, 200);

window.addEventListener('resize', handleResize);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77094068/17007286

This answer works for me